# Ask about opening hours in the next month

Tags: questions, time

I would like to ask to a dealer if they are always open in the next month since in my region it's a popular time for vacations. Would the following work?

> May I ask you [...] and if you stay open all the month in August?

Comment: Recommended reading: [_When should I accept my answer_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) on meta.

Comment: @J.R. good point, I rushed a little bit. I will be more patient next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd understand you, but since I already know that August is a month, there is a bit of duplication. You can say,

> Will you stay open all through August?
>
> *Or . . .*  if you stay open the entire month of August.

"throughout" is alternative to "all through"

Comment: Or *. . . if you stay open the entire month of August.*